# How do I find the limit of the sequence $v_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find the limit of
$$v_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^n$$

I think that $v_n$ is a subsequence of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. So limit is $e$?

But answer is given as $e^{1/3}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a subsequence,  the terms are not in the one you give.

Comment: So how do I find the limit?

Comment: Hint : $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$.

Comment: answering now, but the trick is to take the $Ln$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: or use the hint :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I highly don't recommend my method for this problem, as you can see how annoying it is.  But it is useful to know the general method for taking limits where you need to get the variable out of the exponent.  @NatashaJ

Comment: Subsequences are the key here. Do you see that $c_n=(1+1/(3n+1))^{3n+1}$ is a subsequence of $(1+(1/n))^n$ and hence tends to same limit $e$? Further this means that $b_n=(1+1/(3n+1))^{3n}$ tends to $e$ (why? Use algebra of limits and show that $c_n/b_n\to 1$). Take cube roots and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$v_n\,=\,\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)^n\,=\,\left(\left(1+\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{n+\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{3}}\right)^\frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$v_n=\left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{n}=\left[\left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{3n+1}\right]^{\frac13}\left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{-\frac13}.$$

Comment: Yours is the most suitable answer IMHO. I wrote a comment to the question with a similar strategy and later found your answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma = 3n+1$, now, we can write $n$ as $\dfrac{\gamma-1}{3}$. Rewriting $v_n$ we have that $v_{\gamma} = \left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\dfrac{\gamma-1}{3}}$ or $v_{\gamma} = \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\dfrac{\gamma}{3}}}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}}$. Now, taking the limit as $\gamma \rightarrow \infty$ we obtain: $$\dfrac{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\dfrac{\gamma}{3}}}{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}}.$$ Which is equal to $$\dfrac{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty}\left({\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\gamma}}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}}{1}.$$
Evaluating that limit we obtain that $$\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty}\left({\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\right)^{\gamma}}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{3}} = e^{1/3}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see an easy way to immediately convert it to an $e$ answer,  you can always use the fact that logarithms and exponents are continuous so they interchange with limits,  and using the identity $f(x)=e^{\ln (f(x))}$
so
$$\ln (\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac 1 {3n+1})^n)= \lim_{n\to \infty}\ln ((1 + \frac 1 {3n+1})^n)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln ((1 + \frac 1 {3n+1}))$$
Now you have $0\times \infty$ indefinite form, so we convert the times $n$ to divide by $\frac 1 n$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\ln ((1 + \frac 1 {3n+1}))}{\frac 1 n}$$
Now we have $0/0$,  but L'Hospital's is annoying in this case, so to make it easier we do the variable substitution $x=\frac 1 n$, which convers us to a limit going to 0
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\ln ((1 + \frac 1 {\frac 3 x+1}))}x$$
Rewriting the fraction inside by multiplying by $\frac x x$ gets us to
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\ln ((1 + \frac x {3+x}))}x$$

Knowing we are going to do L'Hospitals, to make my derivivative even easier I am going to add and subtract 3 to the numerator of the fraction with x:
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\ln ((1 + \frac {x+3-3} {3+x}))}x$$

Which lets us split it into $1$ plus the part with the remaining numerator $-3$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\ln ((2 + \frac {-3} {3+x}))}x$$

Now finally using L'Hospitals gets us to
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {3(x+3)^{-2}}{((2 + \frac {-3} {3+x}))}$$

Multiplying top and bottom by $(3+x)^2$ gets us to
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {3}{((2(x+3)^2 + (-3)(x+3)))}$$

Evaluating at $x=0$ gets us to $\frac 1 3$
But that wasn't where our limit went to, that's where the natural log of our limit went to.  So to recover the original limit, we take $e$ to that power.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I will keep it in mind while solving similar problems.

Comment: One more thing! As you said that $v_n$ is not a subsequence of (1+1/n)^n is $((1+\frac{1}{3n+1})^{3n+1})$ is a subsequence of $v_n$? Thank you.

Comment: No,  subsequences have matching terms,  just not as many of them.  like $2,4,6,8...$ is a subsequence of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...$.  If you plug in numbers for $n$ you will see they don't match up at all. @NatashaJ

Comment: Ok! Thanks for clearing it up.